# Keycloak OpenJDK says key material not provided

Tags: keycloak

I can run Keycloak 20.0.5 in development mode, but when I try to run in production mode with the command `bin/kc.sh start --hostname myhostname.com`, it gives the error:

```
Key material not provided to setup HTTPS. Please configure your keys/certificates or start the server in development mode.
```

I have no idea how to configure the keys/certificates. The hostname is configured with Let's Encrypt, but I'm assuming this requires a different certificate. Do I just generate a pair with openssl and provide the filepaths in the command?

Comment: This is a somewhat older question, and I'm having a similar problem. Have you tried using bin/kc.sh start --help to get the list of https options? If so, have you passed in files using --https-certificate-file or -https-certificate-key-file?